# Overflow - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css

I have been working on trying to get a page to display a title at the top of the content pane, and then a scrollable list of products below that so that the title of the product range is displayed at all times. I am sure this is a very simple thing to do - but cannot figure it out.

Currently the actual page (not the test page for which the code is given below) works ok in the sense that I set the heading div to 5% of the height of `.content-container` and then set the scrollable div to 95% with `top: 5%`, both with `position: absolute` applied.

However I would like to place some links in the heading div to different pages (1, 2, 3 etc), which I would like to center vertically if they are shorter than the heading and expand the heading div to match the height of the heading or the links, whichever is smallest. Furthermore I would like the div below the heading to shrink so that it doesn't go below the bottom of the content div as the heading div gets taller. The point of this is because it is for a client who may, or may not, be happy with the heading sizes and so on - therefore the heading div height could easily change. Specifying heights so precisely means that changing the `h1` height could mean 5 changes to the CSS file - something I want to avoid.

The content pane currently has its height fixed to 80% of the page, with the header and footer being 10% each on top of that, so there is no scroll bar at the side of the page and the header / footer are always showing. This is something I would like to keep.

In the code below, `.content-container` is the main content pane - this is contained in another div which is centered using the margin at 50% of the page width. `.test-div` is the div which contains the heading. `.test-div-2` is an attempt to place a div below `.test-div`, in the hope that I can force `.test-div-3` to extend to 100% of its' height but no further, and to display a scroll bar if the content exceeds the height.

So far I have the following, but it doesn't do exactly what I would like it to:

```
<div class="content-container">
    <div class="test-div">
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Dogs</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="test-div-2">
         <div class="test-div-3">
              //Content here
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the css :

```
.content-container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

.test-div {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.test-div-2 {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

.test-div-3 {
    max-height: 100%;
    background-color: #999999;
}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I would like to achieve this without the use of JavaScript / jQuery if possible - pure HTML / CSS solutions only please!

Comment: You have too many closing `</div>` for a start

Comment: Sorry - thats not the cause of the problem though. That was just me being careless in taking out the irrelevant stuff. It is correct in the actual file. Will edit that out now.

Comment: Your <h1> element is closed by a </div>

Comment: @Don no it isn't, just on the same line as a `<div>` clear-fix

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Don - it was in fact correct but I have taken the clear-fix div out now - that was simply there because I used a span set to float: right inside the heading div, to display the page links (1, 2, 3 etc). That, for now, is irrelevant. I am just concentrating on making the lower div change height if I change the height of the h1 at the moment.

Comment: hmm well I can't find an answer - I have tried creating a separate page and working through it step by step, but not getting anywhere. I think the best solution might be to set the heights to 5% (heading) and 95% (scrollable div) using CSS, and then use jQuery to detect the height of the heading div and adjust the scrollable div to suit. I would rather avoid JS since it cuts out 5% (thereabouts) of the users, but there ya go... if the world were perfect then it would be a boring place..!

Answer (score 0):

try
fixing the height of the scrolling div or any block level element and add overflow:scroll property or overflow-y:scroll property

Sample would be

```
    .test-div-2
    {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #CCCCCC;
        overflow: scroll;
        height: 100px;
    }

    .test-div-3
    {
        max-height: 100%;
        background-color: #999999;
    }
</style>

<div class="content-container">
    <div class="test-div">
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">
            Dogs</h1>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="test-div-2">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue
            massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero,
            sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus
            a tellus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
            ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede. Mauris et orci.</p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue
            massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero,
            sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus
            a tellus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
            ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede. Mauris et orci.</p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue
            massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero,
            sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus
            a tellus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
            ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede. Mauris et orci.</p>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue
        massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero,
        sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus
        a tellus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
        ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede. Mauris et orci. </p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This is how I am currently doing it - but fixing the height as a percentage. I would like the size of the scrollable panel to shrink if the heading panel needs more space. Currently I have to change the CSS file in several different places just for one change to the h1 size (or due to the addition of page number links in the heading panel). The point of trying to achieve this is to avoid having to make those changes. I am sure it **must** be possible, but have not found a way myself.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.content-container
            {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                overflow: auto;
            }

.test-div
            {
                position: relative;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }

.test-div-2
            {
                position: relative;
                background-color: #009933;
                max-height:100px;
            }

.test-div-3
            {
                max-height: inherit;
                background-color: #0064ea;
                overflow: scroll;
            }
```

working example
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fC6r4/)

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work - that is based on setting the max-height to a set height. I would like it to shrink if I enlarge the h1 size, or grow if I make the h1 smaller. Thanks for trying though. The content panel is a set height of 80%, but I am not so sure anymore as to whether there is a way to have two divs within that and have the height of the 2nd one set to 100% - the variable height of the 1st one. It seems like such a simple thing to achieve too.